# Labelling a histogram bin with an arrow

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, histogram, annotate

I have a histogram plot which could be replicated with the MWE below:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

pd.Series(np.random.normal(0, 100, 1000)).plot(kind='hist', bins=50)
```

Which creates a plot like this:

[image: example histogram]

How would I then go about labelling the bin with an arrow for a given integer?

For example see below, where an arrow labels the bin containing the integer 300.

[image: example with bin of integer labelled]

EDIT: I should add ideally the y coordinates of the arrow should be set automatically by the height of the bar it is labelling - if possible!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can use `annotate` to add an arrow:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
series = pd.Series(np.random.normal(0, 100, 1000))
series.plot(kind='hist', bins=50, ax=ax)
ax.annotate("",
            xy=(300, 5), xycoords='data',
            xytext=(300, 20), textcoords='data',
            arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="->",
                            connectionstyle="arc3"),
            )
```

In this example, I added an arrow that goes from coordinates (300, 20) to (300, 5).

In order to automatically scale your arrow to the value in the bin, you can use matplotlib `hist` to plot the histogram and get the values back and then use numpy `where` to find which bin corresponds to the desired position.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

nbins = 50
labeled_bin = 200

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

series = pd.Series(np.random.normal(0, 100, 1000))

## plot the histogram and return the bin position and values
ybins, xbins, _ = ax.hist(series, bins=nbins)

## find out in which bin belongs the position where you want the label
ind_bin = np.where(xbins >= labeled_bin)[0]
if len(ind_bin) > 0 and ind_bin[0] > 0:
    ## get position and value of the bin
    x_bin = xbins[ind_bin[0]-1]/2. + xbins[ind_bin[0]]/2.
    y_bin = ybins[ind_bin[0]-1]
    ## add the arrow
    ax.annotate("",
                xy=(x_bin, y_bin + 5), xycoords='data',
                xytext=(x_bin, y_bin + 20), textcoords='data',
                arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="->",
                                connectionstyle="arc3"),
                                )
else:
    print "Labeled bin is outside range"
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, to further expand this question is it possible to automatically set the y position of the arrow based on the height of the bin?

Comment: @BML91 Yes, it is possible ... let me edit my answer

Comment: That works fantastic. Thank you. I'm looking at the documentation to change the weight of the arrow lines, I can't seem to find anything - could you perhaps point me in the right direction?

Comment: I see the `width` keyword for `arrowprops()` however I get a `AttributeError: Unknown property width` when I try and use it.

Comment: @BML91: `width` works fine in my solution below (I updated my code). For this answer you have to use `lw` instead of `width` isnside `arrowprops()`; then it works just fine.

Answer (score 2):

@Julien Spronck showed the best way, I think. Alternatively, you can also use [`arrow`](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/arrow_simple_demo.html);  the example code can be found below. The y-ccordinate is determined automatically by calculating how many elements are in a certain bin (with a certain tolerance which you can define yourself). You can play with the parameters (length of arrow head, length of arrow). Here is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

mySer = pd.Series(np.random.normal(0, 100, 1000))
mySer.plot(kind='hist', bins=50)

# that is where you want to add the arrow
ind = 200
# determine how many elements you have in the bin (with a certain tolerance)
n = len(mySer[(mySer > ind*0.95) & (mySer <  ind*1.05)])

# define length of the arrow
lenArrow = 10
lenHead = 2
wiArrow = 5
plt.arrow(ind, n+lenArrow+lenHead, 0, -lenArrow, head_width=wiArrow+3, head_length=lenHead, width=wiArrow, fc='k', ec='k')

plt.show()
```

This gives you the following output (for 200 instead of 300 as in your example):

[image]